# Django table column is a number

Tags: django, mongodb

Is there a way if a database column uses a number (0,1,2,3,4,5) to set it up as Django model? The database is already created with mongoDB, so I can't make any changes to it, so any easy/fast workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a Django model with different field names and set [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) param to each field so that it corresponds to the database column name. For example:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    firstField = models.IntegerField(db_column='0')
    secondField = models.CharField(db_column='1')
    ...
```

Comment: Also, if you are using an existing database, it would be useful to know about the [`managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed) option for models. Setting `managed = False` will prevent django creating/deleting the table for that model.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not assign to literals in `Python`. You could prefix the column names while creating the fields, e.g. `_0`, but generally a number isn't considered a good field name

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I'd have to get away without changing the database. Hoped there's a secret Django-hack with this. I would never create a column with numbers as name.

Comment: I didn't understand you where _manually_ creating the Django models, in that case @Milorad's solution is what you need.